# Completion of the set of continous functions on $[0,1]$ with the metric $d(x(t),y(t)) = \sup_{t \in [0,1]} t^2|x(t)-y(t)|$.

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces

I am trying to find the completion of $C[0,1]$ with the metric $d(x(t),y(t)) = \sup_{t \in [0,1]} t^2|x(t)-y(t)|$. I understand that this metric space is not complete because the function $f(x) = 1 \text{ if } x = 0, 0 \text{ otherwise}$ can be approximated with $f_n(x) = (1-x)^n$. My guess for the completions is the set
$A := \{ f : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}| f \text{ is continous on } (0,1] \land  \lim_{x \to 0^+} x^2f(x) = 0 \}$.
I need to show two things:
1-) $(A,d)$ is complete.
2-) $(C[0,1],d)$ is dense in $(A,d)$.
I couldn't show either.

Comment: I don't think A is a smaller space then C[0,1]. Because,for example, A contains ()=1 if =0, 0 otherwise.

Comment: A is the set of functions that are continous, except possibly at 0, and that doesn't goes to infinity at 0 faster than 1/x^2.

Comment: I believe the set you described and the one I did are the same.

Comment: Now I agree with you that the set you described is larger than A. But I still disagree with that A is smaller than the set of continous functions. If the set you described is the completion than the function 0 at 0 and $1/x^2$ elsewhere can be approximated with continous functions. I don't see how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible strategy.  Let's write $X$ for the space of continuous function endowed with your unusual metric, $d_X$, and let's write $C$ for the space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ with the usual sup-norm metric, i.e.
$$
d_C(x,y) = \sup_{t \in [0,1]} |x(t) -y(y)|.
$$
It's well-known that $(C,d_C)$ is complete.  Now consider the map $T : X \to C$ via $Tx(t) = t^2 x(t)$.  This is well-defined because the product map $t \mapsto t^2 x(t)$ is continuous.  Moreover,
$$
d_X(x,y) = d_C(Tx,Ty),
$$
so $T$ is an isometric embedding.  This means we can isometrically identify $X$ and $TX \subseteq C$.  From here we deduce that the completion of $X$, say $\bar{X}$, is isometric to the closure of $TX$ in $C$, i.e. $\bar{X} \sim \overline{TX}$.  From here it's straightforward to get the the identification of $\bar{X}$ and $A$ and the two points you're trying to prove.